# Phoenix can't find SSL key even though it exists at location

Tags: ssl, elixir, phoenix-framework

When attempting to run my app in production mode (after successfully compiling):

`MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.server`

I'm getting the following error:

> ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
>               ** (ArgumentError) could not start Cowboy adapter, the file /etc/letsencrypt/live/nhby.in/privkey.pem required by SSL's :keyfile does not exist

*However* that key does actually exist, at that location:

```
$ sudo ls /etc/letsencrypt/live/nhby.in/
cert.pem  chain.pem  fullchain.pem  privkey.pem
```

The key location is defined in the config as per the docs:

`keyfile: Path.expand("../../../../etc/letsencrypt/live/nhby.in/privkey.pem", __DIR__)`

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Do the file permissions allow it to be read?

Comment: That does indeed seem to be the issue. I'm now trying to work out how best to handle that situation without having to manually copy the cert files for each site somewhere else every 3 months :-/ Annoying!

Comment: Consider moving the key into the `priv` directory of your application and reading it from there.

Comment: Hi @RyanBigg, as I say, "without having to manually copy the cert files for each site somewhere else every 3 months". I'd actually overlooked the fact that if you're using nginx you don't actually need to involve phoenix with SSL anyway (and just let nginx deal with it) - so I've kind of bypassed this issue, fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Its long and not pretty, but it works:
`sudo HELLO_WORLD_SSL_KEY_PATH="/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem" HELLO_WORLD_SSL_CERT_PATH="/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem" HELLO_WORLD_SSL_CA_PATH="/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem" PORT=4000 SECRET_KEY_BASE=tLWwWJ1KMQmtkjZjJ56oTPeP5o5Or23I0UMCskyvKxVvcylsayrCJ3N0soaB3KuQ MIX_ENV=prod mix phx.server`